# The smtp feature on Windows 2008 is only for sending?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, iis-6, smtp

I have installed an configured the smpt feature on windows 2008, i can send emails and i can see that on inetpub is a folder mailroot for the incoming mails, but i dont know how to configure the accounts to access the emails received.

I know this smtp server is outdated and is only on 2008 for compatibility, so i assume is just for sending emails?? is that true???

Comment: This is more of a serverfault question, voting to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really a Windows mail server expert, but...

SMTP is a mail transport agent only.  The protocol itself is "just for sending emails."  Where are you sending them?  If they're going to a remote server, you'll need to get them off of that server however you otherwise would (POP and IMAP are popular standards for getting email).  If the local machine *is* the server on which the mail sits and waits to be retrieved, you'll still need a mail server (again, POP or IMAP generally) to listen for incoming connections to fetch the mails.

I wouldn't call SMTP "outdated" as it's still very widely used across the internet.  It's the standard mail transport protocol.  How have you configured this in the past?  Did previous versions of the Windows SMTP service also provide POP/IMAP/etc. support?

Comment: No, the Microsoft full-fledged e-mail server is Exchange Server.  The SMTP server provided with Windows Server is pretty much just to make life easier for web apps which send e-mail -- instead of having to look up the MX record for the recipient, they can just connect to localhost and let the system service figure out the rest.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That's pretty much what I thought.  I guess I'm not sure what the OP is expecting the SMTP service in Windows to be doing other than forwarding messages along to... somewhere.

Comment: mm so that is, i need to install besides the smtp server a mail server? mmm i knew i was missing somenthig, thanks.
BTW, i didnt call outdated the smtp protocol, i was refering to the feature that is included on win2008, because is only available trough iis6- compatibility

Comment: @Vanilla: No problem.  If you don't have Exchange, a Google search for "free Windows mail server" should turn up tons of results from large commercial products to small open-source projects.  There should be plenty to choose from.  SMTP just sends the mail somewhere, there needs to be a server to receive it and host the inboxes for users.